# how to use the cef_menu_handler to create own menu?

Tags: c++, chromium, chromium-embedded

Recently, I've been using the Chromium Embedded Framework to implement a web browser. Now I want to make a context menu that appears on right click, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `OnBeforeMenu` method in `CefMenuHandler`.  In your implementation of that method, display a context menu using the standard technique and return true:

```
bool MyMenuHandler::OnBeforeMenu(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                 const CefMenuInfo& menuInfo)
{
  HMENU hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
  InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, ID_POPUP_FOO, "Foo");
  TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, xpos, ypos, 0, m_hWnd, NULL);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. and I realize it with my method which is likely.

Comment: by the way I want to realize the Drag function, and I override the OnDragEnter method with my ClientHandler, but I can not get the filename of the dragData, why? I can get the filename in the OnDragStart. Does it need JavaScript? looking forward to your answer.